# Create triangle in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I was searching from last 1-2 hours about this question but didn't get any answer if this question is posted before then please give me link and delete this one anyways,

I've a marker in my google map and its like mobile tower

I want to create 10 KM triangle of 120 degree on that marker click,

here's the my code :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker2,"click",function(e){
                    var myLatLng = e.latLng;
                    var Tlat = myLatLng.lat();
                    var Tlng = myLatLng.lng();
                    var Tlng2 = Tlng+(10*0.009);
                    var Tlng3 = Tlng-(10*0.009);
                    var Tlat2 = Tlat+30;
                    var Tlat3 = Tlat-30;

                    var triangleCoords = [
                        new google.maps.LatLng(Tlat2, Tlng2),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(Tlat, Tlng),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(Tlat3, Tlng3)
                      ];
                      alert(triangleCoords);
                        Triangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
                        paths: triangleCoords,
                        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                        strokeWeight: 3,
                        fillColor: "#FF0000",
                        fillOpacity: 0.35
                      });
                        Triangle.setMap(map);
```

My current lat-long is `23.061389, 76.37222199999997` I don't know `10*0.009` is correct formula to find out km or adding 30 degree is correct or not

Comment: relevant: Great Circle Distance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

Comment: I'm using google maps v3

Comment: 1.What is a triangle of 120 degrees? Triangles have 3 interior angles whose sum is 180 degrees. Should the triangle be on the surface of the Earth, (spherical triangle), or tangent to the ground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the link

http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html

this will help you to draw any type of shape polygon, rectangle with source code on Google Map V3.

Comment: Well actually i don't want to create it manually its degree and distance must bhi fixed